# Snowflake - No active warehouse selected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, warehouse

i am just a beginner on snowflake.
I am using trial version.
I am trying run basic command of select * and Db i am taking is Snowflake sample data.
I am getting this error = 000606 (57P03): No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.

what am  i missing?

Comment: Hey Aarushi, first, you must create a warehouse, like "create warehouse xsmall_wh;" then you need to use the warehouse-like so "use warehouse xsmall_wh;"